# If someone has a bacterial throat infection (tonsillitis), can it be transmitted sexually (penetration)?

Tags: infection, sex, sexual-penetration, airborne-transmission

If there is an infection in the throat such as tonsillitis, where transmission is through the air "in droplets when an infected person breathes, coughs, or sneezes", then does this imply that sexual penetration does not cause contagion? Why or why not?